# Concatenate mp3 files in java when one is a silent mp3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mp3

I am trying to join two mp3's using java *SequenceInputStream* in Eclipse. It works fine if both are regular mp3 with sound. But if there is a blank mp3 with no sound in the series, it overrides the previous mp3, and also doesn't show up as a silent break in  final output.
Could the overwriting be because of some header issue? and how can I get a blank silence at the end of the mp3?

Comment: How should we know the reason without knowing what you have coded?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convert your mp3 to a [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) data format (ex : wav)

Then take mesures to determine if it's a silence :

> Calculate the [dB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibels) or [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) value for a group of sound frames and decide
>   at what level it is considered to be 'silence'.

see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800649/detect-silence-when-recording) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918200/identifying-silence-at-the-end-of-an-mp3-using-java) for further details